# how sort items with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a `reducer` and I wanna re-render my other `components` after `case SORT_OLDEST`, and guess what? in ordinary way doesn't work, how i can do this? `case SORT_OLDEST` return sorting but list, but my component doesn't see it

```js
export default (state = allUserComments, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_COMMENT:
      return [createNewComment(action), ...state];
    case SORT_OLDEST:
      return state.reverse();
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: To sort `state.sort()` look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: my components doesn't re-render after case SORT_OLDEST, this is my problem

Comment: then try `state.slice().sort()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reverse` mutates original array. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse). You need to create another.

```
case SORT_OLDEST:
    return [...state].reverse();
```

Comment: It will still mutate the original array.

Answer (score 3):

You need to keep your reducers `pure functions`, meaning you don't want to mutate your state directly. Now I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure `reverse()` mutates the `state` array.

Just copy it before, like `return [...state].reverse();`

Comment: Please move the closing square bracket `]` before `reverse` function, otherwise it will still mutate the original array.

Answer (score 2):

`Array#reverse` mutates the original array (original state).

Use: `return state.slice().reverse();`